# php session problem

Tags: php, session

i'm having a very weird session problem under php:
(works perfectly locally but not on my internet-server)

the problem:

- i'm loading a page - i'm defining a php session via jQuery $.post in an external php script
- i'm refreshing the page - session is still there
- i'm loading a different page - the session is gone (empty)

there's no unset or anything which might reset/clear the session.
i'm using a global php include for the header which triggers session_start();

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: what code do you have right now?

Comment: The session requires the cookie to be set, is the AJAX call setting the cookie?  Most likely not, very common question.

Comment: What's happenning at the HTTP level? Has the session cookie changed? Disappeared?

Comment: check you're not switching from `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com` or vice versa when you load the different page. That will break your sessions.

Comment: i'm assuming that it has something to do with modrewrite - could that be? although i'm always on the same domain ..

Comment: are you sure using session_start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [setting your cookie parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to allow the domain to work across subdomains:

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], $params['path'], '.example.org');
```

Where example.org is your domain name.

Then before printing anything to screen [start your session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();
```

On every page/resource you wish to be able access session data.

Comment: thanks! i think that's it .. i'm using a subdomain for images.